# Merge netCDF files in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have 2 netCDF files (each .nc file has 4 variables: Susceptible, Infected, Recovered and Inhabitable. The dimension of each variable is 64 x 88). I would like to merge these 2 files into a single netCDF file such that the merged file will stack separately Susceptible from the 2 files, Infected from the 2 files, Recovered from the 2 files and Inhabitable from the 2 files.

Here are the 2 files([first](https://www.dropbox.com/s/np6ajwzzznybtog/England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0001.nc?dl=0) and [second](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h475wv7te0szagp/England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0002.nc?dl=0))

Could anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance,
Ashok

Comment: What do you mean with "stack separately"?

Comment: Should the dimensions of your new variables be `(64, 176)` or `(128, 88)`?

Comment: By "stack separately" I mean to place the arrays one on top of the other. For example Susceptible from file1 is for time 0001 and Susceptible from file2 is for time 0002 etc. There is a free tool called Panoply that let's you create an animation if the netcdf files have a time context for the variables (in my case Susceptible, Infected, Recovered).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ncdf4` package will do what you want to do. Have a look at the code below, example for one variable only.

```
#install.packages('ncdf4')
library(ncdf4)

file1 <- nc_open('England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0001.nc')
file2 <- nc_open('England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0002.nc')

# Just for one variable for now
dat_new <- cbind(
  ncvar_get(file1, 'Susceptible'),
  ncvar_get(file2, 'Susceptible'))
dim(dat_new)
var <- file1$var['Susceptible']$Susceptible

# Create a new file
file_new3 <- nc_create(
  filename = 'England_aggr_GPW4_2000_new.nc', 
  # We need to define the variables here
  vars = ncvar_def(
    name = 'Susceptible',
    units = var$units,
    dim = dim(dat_new)))

# And write to it
ncvar_put(
  nc = file_new,
  varid = 'Susceptible',
  vals = dat_new)

# Finally, close the file
nc_close(file_new)
```

---

**Update:**
An alternative approach is using the raster package as shown below. I didn't figure out how to make 4D raster stacks, so I am splitting your data into one `NCDF` file per variable. Would that work for you?

```
#install.packages('ncdf4')
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

var_names <- c('Susceptible', 'Infected', 'Recovered', 'Inhabitable')

for (var_name in var_names) {

  # Create raster stack
  x <- stack(
    raster('England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0001.nc', varname = var_name),
    raster('England_aggr_GPW4_2000_0002.nc', varname = var_name))

  # Name each layer
  names(x) <- c('01', '02') 

  writeRaster(x = x, 
              filename = paste0(var_name, '_out.nc'),
              overwrite = TRUE, 
              format = 'CDF')
}
```

Comment: I'll try to look into this tomorrow

Comment: updated my answer to show an alternative approach using the `raster` package. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thank you @JanLauGe your code does exactly what I want. Much appreciated.

Comment: That's great to hear. Please accept my answer (by clicking the tick mark on the left of the post)

Comment: @JanLauGe I tried your first approach in some CMIP5 files, but I stop in the "# Create a new file" because I received the following error: [1] "Error, passed variable has a dim that is NOT of class ncdim4!"
[1] "Error occurred when processing dim number 1 of variable pr"
Error in ncvar_def(name = "pr", units = var$units, dim = dim(dat_new)) : 
  This dim has class: integer. Could you help me?

Comment: @fvfaleiro It sounds like there is something wrong either with your netcdf file or with the value you are passing on to the `dim` argument of `ncvar_def()`. Double-check those by printing them and testing whether the output matches your expectation

Comment: @JanLauGe the netcdf it's OK, because the CMIP5 follow the rules of the netCDF standard. All of my data is in a  format of three dimension array (longitude, latitude and time). The dim(input.nc) is 144  90  60 and with your approach my dim(dat_new) is 777600 2. Then the file_new3 have the above error. I tryed use abind instead cbind to keep the array format, but it don't works.