# Obtaining raster mean for each longitude and latitude

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, r-raster

I have several .nc files of daily precipitation (january-december from 1981-2010) I stack all of the Januarys using this tutorial: [Merge netCDF files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096730/merge-netcdf-files-in-r)

This is what one of the layers looks:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  31  bands)
dimensions  : 400, 1440, 576000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -50, 50  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : F:\CHIRPS\chirs-v2.0.1981.01.days_p25.nc 
names       : X01 
z-value     : 1981-01-01 
zvar        : precip
```

What I want to do is to obtain the mean value in each longitude and latitude for each layer. Basically is to obtain monthly means from daily data.

I tried the CellStats function like this:

```
promedio <- cellStats(x, stat = 'mean', na.rm = TRUE)
```

But it only gives me one value for each layer.

Any ideas of how to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `cellStats`, which is to summarize one value for each raster layer. Just use the mean function would return a raster layer with mean for each pixel. Please see the following example. `s_avg` is the final output.

```
library(raster)

# Create three example rasters
r1 <- raster(ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
r1[] <- 1
r2 <- r1 + 2
r3 <- r2 + 2

# Create a raster stack
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
s
# class       : RasterStack 
# dimensions  : 5, 5, 25, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
# min values  :       1,       3,       5 
# max values  :       1,       3,       5

# Use cellStats
cellStats(s, stat = "mean")
# layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 
#       1       3       5

# Use mean
s_avg <- mean(s)
s_avg
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 5, 5, 25  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 72, 36  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 3, 3  (min, max)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect, but for what I understand this gives me the average of all of the raster layers right?

Comment: Yes. The mean function on rasterstack creates a raster layer, while cellStats creates a single value for each raster layer.

Answer (score 0):

Not an R solution but you can also do this from the command line (bash) with CDO to make a time mean of all January days.

You can merge all the January files together like this

```
cdo mergetime chirs-v2.0.????.01.days_p25.nc january.nc
```

and then do the time mean:

```
cdo timmean january.nc january_mean.nc
```