# How to merge netcdf files separately in R?

Tags: r, netcdf, cdo-climate

I am a user of R and would like some help in the following:
I have two netcdf files (each of dimensions 30x30x365) and one more with 30x30x366. These 3 files contain a year's worth of daily data, where the last dimension refers to the time dimension. I wanted to combine them separately i.e. I wanted the output file to contain 30x30x1096.

Note: I have seen a similar question but the output results in an average (i.e. 30x30x3) which I do not want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge netCDF files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096730/merge-netcdf-files-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

from the comment I see below you seem to want to merge 3 files in the time dimension.  As an alternative to R, you could do this quickly from the command line using cdo (climate data operators):

```
cdo mergetime file1.nc file2.nc file3.nc mergedfile.nc
```

or using wildcards:

```
cdo mergetime file?.nc mergedfile.nc
```

cdo is easy to install under ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install cdo
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what dimensions and variables you have, this may be enough to get you started:

```
library(ncdf4)

output_data <- array(dim = c(30, 30, 1096))
files <- c('file1.nc', 'file2.nc', 'file3.nc')
days <- c(365, 365, 366)

# Open each file and add it to the final output array
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    nc <- nc_open(files[i])
    input_arr <- ncvar_get(nc, varid='var_name')
    nc_close(nc)

    # Calculate the indices where each file's data should go
    if (i > 1) {
        day_idx <- (1:days[i]) + sum(days[1:(i-1)])
    } else {
        day_idx <- 1:days[i]
    }

    output_data[ , , day_idx] <- input_arr
}

# Write out output_data to a NetCDF. How exactly this should be done depends on what
# dimensions and variables you have.

# See here for more:
#   https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/display/OET/Creating+a+netCDF+file+with+R
```

Comment: @ C. Braun I forgot to mention, the file names are file1.nc, file 2.nc and file3.nc. The variable name is 'sst' where 30x30 are longitude x latitude and 365/366 indicate days. Could you please update? (I'm actually a beginner here)